# Chudnovsky binary splitting and factoring

Tags: c, recursion, gmp, pi, factoring

In [this article](http://www.craig-wood.com/nick/articles/pi-chudnovsky/), a fast recursive formulation of the Chudnovsky pi formula using binary splitting is given. In python:

```
C = 640320
C3_OVER_24 = C**3 // 24
def bs(a, b):
    if b - a == 1:
        if a == 0:
            Pab = Qab = 1
        else:
            Pab = (6*a-5)*(2*a-1)*(6*a-1)
            Qab = a*a*a*C3_OVER_24
        Tab = Pab * (13591409 + 545140134*a) # a(a) * p(a)
        if a & 1:
            Tab = -Tab
    else:
        m = (a + b) // 2
        Pam, Qam, Tam = bs(a, m)
        Pmb, Qmb, Tmb = bs(m, b)

        Pab = Pam * Pmb
        Qab = Qam * Qmb
        Tab = Qmb * Tam + Pam * Tmb
    return Pab, Qab, Tab

N = int(digits/DIGITS_PER_TERM + 1)
# Calclate P(0,N) and Q(0,N)
P, Q, T = bs(0, N)
one = 10**digits
sqrtC = sqrt(10005*one, one)
return (Q*426880*sqrtC) // T
```

This method is already very fast, but it's mentioned that an implementation on the GMP library website, [gmp-chudnovsky.c](https://gmplib.org/download/misc/gmp-chudnovsky.c), also factors the numerator and denominator in binary splitting. As the code is optimized and hard for me to understand, what is the general idea behind how this is done? I can't tell if fractions are simplified, numbers are kept in factorized form instead of being entirely multiplied, or both.

Here is a code sample of the binary splitting:

```
/* binary splitting */
void
bs(unsigned long a, unsigned long b, unsigned gflag, long int level)
{
  unsigned long i, mid;
  int ccc;

  if (b-a==1) {
    /*
      g(b-1,b) = (6b-5)(2b-1)(6b-1)
      p(b-1,b) = b^3 * C^3 / 24
      q(b-1,b) = (-1)^b*g(b-1,b)*(A+Bb).
    */
    mpz_set_ui(p1, b);
    mpz_mul_ui(p1, p1, b);
    mpz_mul_ui(p1, p1, b);
    mpz_mul_ui(p1, p1, (C/24)*(C/24));
    mpz_mul_ui(p1, p1, C*24);

    mpz_set_ui(g1, 2*b-1);
    mpz_mul_ui(g1, g1, 6*b-1);
    mpz_mul_ui(g1, g1, 6*b-5);

    mpz_set_ui(q1, b);
    mpz_mul_ui(q1, q1, B);
    mpz_add_ui(q1, q1, A);
    mpz_mul   (q1, q1, g1);
    if (b%2)
      mpz_neg(q1, q1);

    i=b;
    while ((i&1)==0) i>>=1;
    fac_set_bp(fp1, i, 3);  /*  b^3 */
    fac_mul_bp(fp1, 3*5*23*29, 3);
    fp1[0].pow[0]--;

    fac_set_bp(fg1, 2*b-1, 1);  /* 2b-1 */
    fac_mul_bp(fg1, 6*b-1, 1);  /* 6b-1 */
    fac_mul_bp(fg1, 6*b-5, 1);  /* 6b-5 */

    if (b>(int)(progress)) {
      printf("."); fflush(stdout);
      progress += percent*2;
    }

  } else {
    /*
      p(a,b) = p(a,m) * p(m,b)
      g(a,b) = g(a,m) * g(m,b)
      q(a,b) = q(a,m) * p(m,b) + q(m,b) * g(a,m)
    */
    mid = a+(b-a)*0.5224;     /* tuning parameter */
    bs(a, mid, 1, level+1);

    top++;
    bs(mid, b, gflag, level+1);
    top--;

    if (level == 0)
      puts ("");

    ccc = level == 0;

    if (ccc) CHECK_MEMUSAGE;

    if (level>=4) {           /* tuning parameter */
#if 0
      long t = cputime();
#endif
      fac_remove_gcd(p2, fp2, g1, fg1);
#if 0
      gcd_time += cputime()-t;
#endif
    }

    if (ccc) CHECK_MEMUSAGE;
    mpz_mul(p1, p1, p2);

    if (ccc) CHECK_MEMUSAGE;
    mpz_mul(q1, q1, p2);

    if (ccc) CHECK_MEMUSAGE;
    mpz_mul(q2, q2, g1);

    if (ccc) CHECK_MEMUSAGE;
    mpz_add(q1, q1, q2);

    if (ccc) CHECK_MEMUSAGE;
    fac_mul(fp1, fp2);

    if (gflag) {
      mpz_mul(g1, g1, g2);
      fac_mul(fg1, fg2);
    }
  }

  if (out&2) {
    printf("p(%ld,%ld)=",a,b); fac_show(fp1);
    if (gflag)
      printf("g(%ld,%ld)=",a,b); fac_show(fg1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't look at the full code, but I had a quick glance at it in order to understand better the excerpt you provide in your question.

In order to answer to some points from your question, have a look at this piece of code first:

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned long max_facs;
  unsigned long num_facs;
  unsigned long *fac;
  unsigned long *pow;
} fac_t[1];
```

It defines a new type as a structure (if you don't know C at all, let's say it is like a rudimentary Pyhton object embedding variables but no methods). This type allows to handle integer numbers as two integer values and two arrays (say: two lists):

- greatest factor
- number of factors
- list of factors
- list of (corresponding) powers for these factors

In the same time the code keeps the *same* numbers as big integers from the libgmp type (this is what is meant by `mpz_t p` and `mpz_t g` in the arguments of the function).

Now, what about the function you are showing. It is called `fac_remove_gcd`; the initial `fac` has to do with the name of the previously described type; the two following words are easy to understand: *divide two integer numbers of type `fac` by their gcd*.

The C code iterates over the two lists of factors in both lists; it is easy to synchronize both lists since factors are ordered (section of the code around the `else if` and `else` statements); whenever two common factors are detected (initial `if` statement), dividing is a matter of simple substraction: the smallest power is substracted in both lists of powers for this factor (for instance with a=2*5^3*17 and b=3*5^5*19, the value 3 will be substracted in the lists of powers for *a* and *b* at the position corresponding to factor 5 leading to a=2*5^0*17 and b=3*5^2*19).

During this operation a number (of the same `fac` type) is created and called `fmul`; it is obviously the gcd of both numbers.

After this step the gcd called `fmul` and being of the `fac` type is converted to a GMP big integer with the function (also in the code of the program) called `bs_mul`. This allows to compute the GCD as a big integer in order to synchronize the new values of the divided numbers in both forms: big integers and special `fac` type. Once the GCD is computed as a big integer, it is easy to divide both initial numbers by the GCD.

**Thus the functions acts upon two versions of each initial numbers.**

Hope it can help.

Comment: This is helpful, but I am more interested in how the numerator and denominator can be factored during binary splitting, given that `q(a, b)` is not calculated just as a product of two numbers. I've edited the code sample given.

Comment: I'm guessing factors are added to the factor list during multiplication, from `fac_set_bp` and `fac_mul_bp`?

Answer (score 6):

The following comments are key:

```
/*
    g(b-1,b) = (6b-5)(2b-1)(6b-1)
    p(b-1,b) = b^3 * C^3 / 24
    q(b-1,b) = (-1)^b*g(b-1,b)*(A+Bb).
*/
```

```
/*
    p(a,b) = p(a,m) * p(m,b)
    g(a,b) = g(a,m) * g(m,b)
    q(a,b) = q(a,m) * p(m,b) + q(m,b) * g(a,m)
*/
```

```
/*
          p*(C/D)*sqrt(C)
    pi = -----------------
             (q+A*p)
*/
```

Observe:

1. If we scale both `p` and `q` by a factor of `k` in the final division, it doesn't affect the result.
2. When computing the merge operation which corresponds to the second set of comments, if we were to scale each of `p(a,m)`, `g(a,m)`, and `q(a,m)` by `k` then that factor would simply be carried through to `p(a,b)`, `g(a,b)`, `q(a,b)`; similarly if we were to scale each of `p(m,b)`, `g(m,b)`, and `q(m,b)` then that factor would carry through.
3. The line

   ```
   fac_remove_gcd(p2, fp2, g1, fg1);
   ```

   is effectively

   ```
   k = gcd(p2, g1);
   p2 /= k; // p(m,b) /= k
   g1 /= k; // g(a,m) /= k
   ```

   This has the net effect of downscaling `p(a,b)`, `g(a,b)`, and `q(a,b)` by that `gcd`. By the previous two observations, this downscaling carries through cleanly all the way to the final result.

#### Postscript

I've tried three ways of implementing the factoring in Python.

- Tracking the factorisations using immutable lists slows things down horrendously because there's far too much busy-work maintaining the lists.
- Using gmpy's `gcd` does not give a speed-up
- Pre-calculating a list of primes up to `6 * N` (i.e. which might divide `g`) and testing each of those primes slows things down by a factor of 2 to 3.

I conclude that getting a speed-up with this approach requires using mutable state to track the factorisations, so it's a big hit for maintainability.

Comment: Hi from PPCG! Do you think the code maintains a list of factors and their powers instead of representing the number in full? This is what I got from `fac_set_bp`, `fac_mul` and related functions. Also, gcc can optimize GMP in ways python obviously can't.

Comment: As Baruchel's answer already pointed out, it does both: it keeps a `mpz_t` representation and a `fac_t` representation for `p` and `g`.